# Search filtering in question and answer section - Profile Page

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, profile-page, filtering

It is very difficult to find the answers written by myself. I do this for reference purposes and had to go through page by page manually to find the question or answer I am looking in the profile section.

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I mean adding a search filtering mechanism in "Question & Answer" section in Profile Page

Comment: The search box at the top comes with your user id filled in when you visit your own profile. If you do a search on that page, it will search your posts.

Comment: Your can search like, `user:me is:q "searchTerm"` for your own questions and `user:me is:a "searchTerm"` for your own answers

Comment: Status-already-there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search within your own questions and answers, you can use the following advance search options:

Within your own questions: `user:me is:q "searchTerm"`
Within your own answers: `user:me is:a "searchTerm"`

You can find more options in the [search help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)